# Qt application cannot run in release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, debugging, release

I am using visual studio 2017 and qt 5.12.9 msvc2017_64.

When I compiled the program in "Debug x64", the application worked fine. When I compiled the program in "Release x64", the program can be compiled successfully without any error, but the application cannot be opened and showed nothing (no warning, etc.). I used the windeployqt.

Then, I tried to debug the program in "Release x64" and the visual studio showed me something in the following image.

[image]

What should I do to make the program run in release? Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you linking with the release version of Qt? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: My guess is there is some bug in QtVisualization

Comment: It appears to be using the Release `Qt5Gui.dll` in debug mode it should be named `Qt5Guid.dll`

Comment: @drescherjm. When I double clicked the exe of release version, it showed nothing and I debugged the program in "Release x64". Maybe the information shown in the image resulted from debugging in "Release x64" and have nothing to do with the exe of release version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because windeployqt will not copy all required dll to release the directory.
There is some missing dlls that you need to copy manualy.
There is two way to find it out.

1. Use a dependency walker. identify the missing library and copy it to your release directory.
2. Copy the following folder from **C:\Qt\Qt5.12\5.12.9\msvc2017_64** to the folder where, your exe is located

```
plugins
qml
translations
mkspecs
```

Copy all dll from C:\Qt\Qt5.12\5.12.9\msvc2017_64\bin folder to root folder of your exe.

also create **qt.conf** filed and all following lines to it

```
[Paths] 
Prefix=. 
Libraries=lib 
Plugins=plugins 
Qml2Imports=qml 
Translations=translations 
Headers=include 
Documentation=doc
```

Now run your exe. after the program runs. try to delete some dll. if the program is using any dll, it will not get deleted. by doing this unused dll will be removed. similar try with qml folder and plugin folder.